# Multi Raster Random Forest in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, gis, random-forest

I am trying to set up a randomForest in R to classify a raster image based on other raster images. My training data is a completely populated raster image, and I would like to train a number of other rasters to try and create a raster output based on the initial raster. An example of the code would be something like:

`rf1 <- randomForest(trainingRaster1 ~ raster1 + raster2 + raster3)`

...where `trainingRaster1` is my actual known values in raster format, and `raster1` through `rasterN` are other raster images in which I would like to use to predict what `trainingRaster1` is. I understand you are to use a training class of vectors or points to train a series of raster, but in my case I would like to product an output raster using a raster as a training class (as I have a fully populated raster image in which to train the other rasters on). My questions are: is this possible? Can I use a raster to train my other raster datasets? Can I use multiple raster datasets as input variables? What would the formula look like? Do I need to grid all data to the same extent and resolution? I would really like to use randomForest within R, but is there a different approach? What would an example code look like? Finally, how would I use the model, once run, to create a raster without inputting the training dataset? Thank you very much in advance. I have read and watched examples of randomForest but have not seen it used the way I intend. I am wondering if it will require some deviation from the normal use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster cells are just data points. So if (or once) they line up (the same extent and resolution), you can do

Example data

```
library(raster)
# predictors
logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
# generate "known values"
set.seed(1)
obs <- sqrt(sum(logo)) + sample(ncell(logo))/500
names(obs) <- "obs"
```

Fit the model

```
s <- stack(obs, logo)
d <- as.data.frame(s)
library(randomForest)
m <- randomForest(obs~., d, ntree=50)
```

predict

```
p <- predict(s, m)
names(p) <- "pred"
plot(stack(obs, p))
```

Note how the image improved.

In the `predict` step you could replace `s` with another set of predictor data with the same names. So you can fit your model based on the data for one year, for which you have the predictors (e.g. satellite or climate data), and the observations (e.g. crop yield), but then you can predict to another year, for which you have the predictors, but not the observations of interest.

It may be that you cannot do this because the raster data is too large for RAM. In that case you can take a sample, or create multiple models on subsets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. I have two questions: is it possible to use a blank data frame as the `obs` variable after training the random forest? What I mean is, let us say I have a full training dataset to use as `obs` for one year, as well as a series of other datasets I would like to use as predictor data. For the next year, the training data is not available. Can I use random forest to populate the data frame if all I have is a blank `obs` data frame and complete '`d` datasets, or `logo` in this case? Also, if I do have multi year data, can I repeat this and add to the robustness of RF?

Comment: I already the first part of your question, but I have expanded the answer to -hopefully- be more clear. If you have multiple years, you could repeat this and make multiple predictions and average. But I would make a single model based on all data. In principle (e.g., no RAM limitations) you can `rbind` the data.frame's `d`.